# Python: creating a new function from math module functions

Tags: python

Good evening, I'd like to have the function `x^3+x^2+sin(x)` (for example) to work with, an intuitive try was this:

```
import math as m

h(x)=m.pow(x,3)+m.pow(x,2)+m.sin(x)
```

However I get a `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

How could I mix math module (or another module, it doesn't matter) functions in order to get the function I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest Python can get to your example would be with a lambda.

```
import math as m

h = lambda x: m.pow(x,3)+m.pow(x,2)+m.sin(x)
```

But lambdas are generally for anonymous functions. If you're going to give it a name, use `def` instead.

```
import math as m

def h(x):
    return m.pow(x,3)+m.pow(x,2)+m.sin(x)
```